# Node.js response status 404, keep url

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm struggling to achieve a 404 status page.

When you type a url, lets say: mypage.com/products/1412

If that product (with that id) doesn't exist, I want it to stay on that page, but the page should render a "404 page". I have a 404 page, which is a React Component already. Every error on the site redirects to this view where this component is rendered...

The code looks like this:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
 Location: '/error' + encodeURI(req.url),
});
```

What's happening here is that when you type in a wrong product that doesn't exist from the API, it redirects me to 'error/product/id'

I want it still to stay on 'product/id' but render a 404 page...

Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: why not to use `Location: '/error'` then? What's the route of 404 page?

Comment: Because if I use `Location: '/error'` the url will be mypage.com/error

I want to keep the url as mypage.com/product/id

But render a 404 page (that is not static). The 404 page is a React component. How can I tell node to render a react component? If it was a static html page it wouldn't be much of a problem...

Comment: there are several ways to do it: 1) create a static page and render react component there, redirect to it in case of such error 2) render some initial page anyway on any request (wrong/correct) with some react app and render either 404 component or good one 3) generate static page based on your component etc

Comment: and use a framework like Express/Koa instead, it would be much easier for you :)